# Flag a Question dialog bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, flag-dialog

I was attempting to flag a question which is when I came across a strange thing.

I clicked the ***flag*** link which opened a Dialog where it asked for options like "very low quality" and "other" radio buttons.

Here first I selected the "very low quality" radio button and after a while, I thought I should go for the "other" radio button.

So I clicked on it, and thought of entering some content. But again I changed my mind and went to "very low quality" radio button. I clicked it and now the "flag question" button was still disabled.

Can anyone tell me why this has happened?

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce this, works for me.

Comment: select other, click inside the edit column, without typing anything again select "very low quality". the button will be disabled. This is how I got it.

Comment: Repro with FF6 Beta. Clicking the RadioButton *shortly* does reactivate and instantly deactivate the button again. *Holding* the click for half a second does reactivate the button.

Comment: oh fine. But I believe that there will be someone like me who might not know this.

Comment: Reproduced.  Click back and forth between ***very low quality*** and ***other***.  Fill in some text in the ***other*** dialog.  Then click ***very low quality***, and the ***Flag Question*** button will be disabled.

Comment: Oh. Weird. I managed to reproduce this at one point, but not any other point. Following @Bobby's comment, it seems to be some measure of haste involved, but I can't reliably reproduce it. IE8/XP here. What I have noticed, though, is that if you do get the button disabled, then clicking the "very low quality" radio a second time will usually fix it.

Comment: Repro in Chrome using the info from @Bobby: clicking it *shortly* triggers the bug. Strange.

Comment: @Grace Note Could you please follow my previous comment and try?

Comment: My guess: the unblur event of the text field checks for sufficient length of the comment and the onfocus of the radio button enables the button. A timing difference causes the unblur to be handled *after* the onfocus *if* the click doesn't take long. Therefore, the button is re-enabled and re-disabled in quick succession.

Comment: Trying your original comment did not work, that was my initial test that did not reproduce (and was my original comment noting such).

Comment: You really have to work at this to see the problem. And anyway, clicking the radio button again solves it.

Comment: @Grace Note Well, I am using Mozilla. I am not sure about other browsers though!

Comment: @GraceNote -- i repro'd it in Chrome 12 Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix for this will be pushed tonight.

Comment: couldn't see any fix yet

Comment: You're still seeing the issue? What browser are you using?

Comment: We've had a few issues lately with our CDN - try clearing your cache and getting the latest javascript.

Comment: @JarrodDixon - I think it's been long enough that we can no longer blame this on the CDN or caching.  Still seeing it with Chrome 19.latest, as are others: [Flag button gets perma-disabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133393)