# "Flag post" link is deactivated when changing flag reasons

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, flags, flag-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag a Question dialog bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99882/flag-a-question-dialog-bug)

Here's a tiny annoyance. Steps to reproduce:

- Find a bad answer (or question, let's assume an answer here)
- Click the "flag" link
- Click "other". Note the 'Flag answer' button correctly being disabled.
- Think "Nah, just 'not an answer' will do" and click it.
- See the 'Flag answer' button **still disabled**

Obviously, closing the flag dialog and reopening it restores it. However, it should be possible for me to flag a post even if I decide to change the reason while I'm in the middle of flagging.

Could probably be fixed by adding a small event listener.

---

[image]