# "Flag" button is disabled when the "other" reason has been chosen

Tags: bug, flags, flag-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Flag a Question dialog bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99882/flag-a-question-dialog-bug)

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Find a question or an answer
- Click `flag` and choose "it needs moderator attention" » "other".

  [image]
- Click "it is spam"
- The form submission button is not actionable

  [image]

---

**What should happen:**

- The submission button should become activated again when a checkbox other than "other" is chosen.

Comment: Reated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99882/flag-a-question-dialog-bug and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102816/flag-post-link-is-deactivated-when-changing-flag-reasons In fact, it's a dupe of the first - other than it is marked as status-completed.

Comment: Hm, has this been fixed already?

Comment: Evidently not entirely if people are experiencing problems. That was a considerable time ago, so perhaps a regression. Although, I can't reproduce on SO with Chrome.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment No, I mean the very issue I'm talking about. I couldn't reproduce it anymore when I just tried it.

Comment: Woah woah woah, does this happen when flagging questions *and* answers?

Answer (score 2):

Reproduced!

However, I have found a workaround and the source of the bug: When you select the "other" flag reason, the "Flag answer" button  is deactivated *until you enter 10 characters*, per the text:

> enter at least 10 characters

Just type ten characters into the "other" box and you can flag away!  Preferably, though, one of the devs could fix the validation code and you wouldn't have to do this.

After entering 12 characters:

> [image]

After selecting the "It is spam" radio button:

> [image]

Comment: Well, until this is fixed, I think simply not doing that is a viable workaround.

Comment: Or canceling the dialog (with "cancel" in the lower left, the `[esc]` key, or the `X` in the top left) and clicking "flag" again.  I just wanted to clarify that it was the minimum character restriction that was causing the bug.

Comment: You can also work around this by clicking another radio button -- the first radio button leaves the `Flag Question` button disabled, the second radio button enables the `Flag Question` button.