# Question wrongly marked as exact duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I have noticed that quite a few people have read this question:

[php mongodb find nth entry in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572485/php-mongodb-find-nth-entry-in-collection/12578257)

Wrongly and assumed it was a duplicate of:

[Get n-th element of an array in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223273/get-n-th-element-of-an-array-in-mongo)

However if you read the two questions you will realise that they are completely different.

I normally wouldn't moan about this but it gives a huge message sending most future viewers to the wrong question giving the wrong answer and the wrong information to solve the problem. Call me OCD but it's cataloged wrongly.

I have cast a re-open vote on the question however I am hoping we could get together and reverse this because clearly the OP was not looking for the `$slice` command and wasn't even looking at getting a range of a subdocument from a root document. So the "duplicate" is of a completely different problem. He is actually trying to get a random document from within a collection in a performant manner (and of course `$slice` is useless there).

Answer (score 7):

The question itself look and smelled like a duplicate to passers-by.  The titles were similar, the actions the users wanted to take were quite similar. It's only to people that know PHP and MongoDB that these questions *weren't* duplicates.

So in a way, the OP contributed to this issue by not being specific enough in his title.  However, you're right, the question is not a duplicate.

I've re-opened the question.

In the future, please flag the question with the reason 'other' and explain your reason for wanting it re-opened. Bringing normal, everyday problems to meta that bother you is not really the best use of Meta.

Also, editing the question to point out why the question isn't a duplicate would have been useful. You don't yet have the reputation to edit, but you can 'suggest' an edit (using the `edit` link), and if it was a good edit, it would be accepted by the community.

Comment: The system only askes if I wanna re-open it it doesn't really state any good practices to getting it reopened and I am unsure what you mean by "other", do you mean this question or that question?

Comment: On the question you want to re-open, there's a link that says, "Flag". Click it. Then click "Other" as the reason for the flag. Then state why you want it re-opened there. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120085/flag-button-is-disabled-when-the-other-reason-has-been-chosen

Comment: Aha, thanks lol I should have been more observant :\ sorry