# Flag button is disabled when selecting "it is spam"

Tags: bug, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag a Question dialog bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99882/flag-a-question-dialog-bug)
>   [“Flag” button is disabled when the “other” reason has been chosen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120085/flag-button-is-disabled-when-the-other-reason-has-been-chosen)

I check `other` under `it needs ♦ moderator attention`. Then I can't change it to `it is spam` and submit the form. It might require going back and forth between `it needs ♦ moderator attention` and `it is spam` to reproduce.

[image]

Comment: (hmmmm.... I suspect trying to repro this *here* might be a bad idea... I should really move to a dev sandbox... but it is *so tempting*....)

Comment: Also works if you select `very low quality`. You can then click any of the other upper level options to reset the moderator attention radio.

Comment: can you describe what you *do* see, or what happens? it seems to work fine for me ... also, what browser are you using?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Hit flag, click "Other", click spam, click "it needs mod attention" again ("other" should still be enabled magically) then click spam -> the "flag question" is still disabled

Comment: im on chrome 18.

Comment: Repro on iPad (Terra). I'm getting _stranger_ behavior here. Other>spam>other. The moment I click "spam" after this, the flag button enables itself for a split second and then disables itself. Code reuse?

Comment: I get different behaviour depending on clicking buttons vs text; will investigate

Comment: This is only partially true for me. If you click on the actual radio button or "other" text, then try to click on "it is spam" it *doesn't* re-enable the button. If you click inside the textarea and let it auto-select "other" then click "it is spam" it *does* get re-enabled.

Comment: No repro for me here... Firefox 11.